# psql is not prompting me for a password, then denies access

Tags: postgresql, permissions, psql, password

I'm using Postgres 9.4 on Debian Linux.  I created a database with a user, `cindex` with access to the database.  Yet when I try and login at the command line, I'm not even prompted for a password:

```
myuser@myuserserver:~ $ psql -Ucindex cindex
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "cindex"
```

What else do I need to do to enable the user?  Below you can see the privileges that I have already set up:

```
postgres@myuserserver:~$ psql
psql (9.4.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA cindex TO cindex;
GRANT
postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 cindex    | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =T/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | cindex=c/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 cindex    |                                                | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Comment: You need to check the contents of your `pg_hba.conf`. Think of it as the PostgreSQL server firewall configuration.

Comment: And what am I looking to change in there?

Comment: The pg_hba file specifies `peer` or `ident` authentication.  Those don't use passwords, so there is no point in asking you for a password.  You are looking to change `peer` or `ident` to be `md5`, which does use passwords. (or perhaps to `ldap`, or `scram-sha-256 (v10 only), or maybe one of the more obscure methods which uses passwords)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Peer authentication

This means it's using a unix socket connection, and connections for unix sockets are set to use `peer` authentication in `pg_hba.conf`. It just checks that the unix user name is the same as the postgres user name requested, and doesn't care about passwords.

If you want password auth, use `md5` auth in `pg_hba.conf` instead.

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

The way PostgreSQL splits authentication between SQL configuration and a config file is definitely confusing, so you're not alone. Being able to set a password for a user, but having that password be ignored in some contexts and used in others, takes some getting used to. Once you understand the system it makes sense but it's definitely not discoverable and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, the answer was incorrect rules order in `pg_hba.conf`. Before:

```
local    all     all     peer
local    myuser  mydb    md5
```

since for local connections "all-all" rules was the first, and `myuser` with `mydb` was a part of that all, psql assumed that connection type is `peer` and denied me access.

After

```
local    myuser  mydb    md5
local    all     all     peer
```

This way, for a specific user, password auth is used, just as I want it to be.